# Create record for authenticated user in tastypie/Django

Tags: post, tastypie

Very simple: I have a User resource and a Item resource, as soon as a logged in user creates a new Item, I want the system to automatically create that new Item resource with `user_id` of the authenticated user.. simple right?

usual setup:

```
class Item( models.Model ):
    user = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name="item" )
    nCries = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, )

class ItemResource( MyModelResource ) :

user = fields.ToOneField( 'app.api.UserResource','user',full=True,null=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'item'
    authorization= Authorization()
    authentication = SessionAuthentication()
```

How do I do this with tastypie?

`obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):` wouldn't do it for me since I have no access to the request object to change the bundle.user.id to the authenticated user id.

Any idea appreciated!

THX

Comment: What about the `bundle.request` object?

Comment: wow, I need to learn more it seems; bundle has no indication of request when examining (e.g. raise Exception( bundle) ). Chee. Please create an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The can be also accessed via `bundle.request` attribute. Note that this attribute is not required, and as such might not always be available (usually when using the method outside of the regular tastypie request-response cycle).